# Outdated CentOS 5.11 and https

Tags: tls, httpd, centos-5

I have CentOS 5.11 on server, which is too outdated.

It has Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) and Apache Tomcat/5.5.25

Unfortunately migration to the new OS is not possible at the moment.

The website hosted on the server https://www.example.com returns

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com.
Peer using unsupported version of security protocol.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

This website might not support the TLS 1.2 protocol
```

https://www.ssllabs.com/ says

> The server supports only older protocols, but not the current best TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3. Grade capped to C
>
> This server supports TLS 1.0. Grade capped to B.

The hosting provider advise to upgrade the server as they say they cannot install new
Let`s Encrypt SSL.

I wonder is there any chance to make https work again?

I`ll be thankful if someone show me the way to solve the issue without moving to the server with the latest OS/distro.

Comment: You will definitely need to get a newer server installed to do anything. There is a good workaround in a posted answer, but maybe, now is a good moment to upgrade the server anyway.

Comment: I could`t say better, but the web site we have there is too old Java legacy project. Did not find the coder who can estimate the work and then make it work on the new server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely cannot upgrade the server, one alternative is to set up another adjacent server to act as a 'reverse proxy' and let it handle TLS in front of your old server.

```
internet -->TLSv1.3--> rev.proxy -->TLSv1.0--> old server
```

The LE certificate would need to be set up on the proxy, whereas the old server only needs a certificate that the proxy itself would accept. (It could even be plain HTTP between the proxy and the server, as long as they're local.)